# Why doesn't pylint warn me about using nonexistent class members?

Tags: python, pylint, duck-typing

I'm coming to python from a C++ background, and I like to use tools like pylint to catch obvious errors that a compiler would normally catch.  However, pylint considers this code to be okay:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Test module"""

class MyException(Exception):
    """A custom exception"""
    def __init__(self, error_code, message):
        self.error_code = error_code
        super(MyException, self).__init__(message)

try:
    raise MyException(123, 'One Two Three')
except MyException as err:
    print err.errCode
    print err.message
```

The problem being, of course, that "print err.errCode" results in runtime error.

Is this just an oversight in pylint's checking, or is there something about python that would make referencing the seemingly nonexistent errCode valid?

Obviously you could be catching a subclass of MyException which included that field, but if you're in a scope with an explicit MyException object, I would think you would not want to be referring to stuff that might exist in a subclass.  It's certainly not an error (I can think of many scenarios where you might want to might take different actions based on the capabilities of a function's parameter), but it certainly seems warning-worthy.

Comment: Keep in mind that all the fields come into existence at run time. Since some fields may be set and read conditionally, producing accurate warnings (i.e. figuring out what actually gets run) essentially reduces to solving the halting problem.

Comment: Python has dynamic types, which means it's not possible to determine what attributes a class instance has until runtime and even then it can vary from moment-to-moment. This is why testing is so important when using the language.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Is this because although in my example, error_code and message seem like actual variables, behind the scenes, these are actually implemented as dictionary entries, and the fact that I don't need to reference them as MyException['error_code'] is just syntactic sugar on Python's part?

Comment: Pretty much. A Python object is basically just a big dict and you can add/remove fields as much as you want at runtime.

Comment: @martineau: I had understood that Python is type-safe, meaning that once you assigned a value to my_var, it had to remain that type.  So how could its legal operations vary from moment to moment?  Is it possible for a class to change its implementation details at run time?  Or is it just that the catch block is one of the few cases in Python where you know the type of a variable, so it's not worth putting a special pylint check for this?

Comment: @Steve: Say you had a `class Foo(object): pass`, and created an instance of it `foo = Foo()`. Afterwards it would be possible to set `foo.x = 42` thereby adding an `x` attribute to (just that) class instance. Later on you could also `del foo.x` and get rid of it.

Comment: @martineau: Good to know - thanks for the clarification.  I'm only a few days into learning python, and I'm still looking for a good resource to really understand how to work with python (particularly coming from my statically-typed background); either the texts are too basic, or they just dive into a lot of slick features of the language, without covering how it actually works.  Feel free to recommend a good learning resource.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing#Variation_across_programming_languages): '...Python is "strongly typed" in the sense that typing errors are prevented at runtime and they do little implicit type conversion, but these languages make no use of static type checking'.

Comment: FWIW, I found the books _Python in a Nutshell_ and the _Python Cookbook_ series very enlightening (having a strong C++ background myself).

Comment: I believe pylint does report access to names that are not set in `__init__` or are not class names. See http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#typecheck-checker and E1101 and E1103. Obviously the checks are not foolproof, since python objects are dynamic, but they should be there.

Comment: @SteveBroberg:  A handy rule for dealing with Python typing:  Don't think of type safety in terms of _variables_, but in terms of _values_.  You can assign anything to the name `x`, and later assign something completely different.  A variable like `x` is just a label; it has no type of its own.  Type safety (especially in Python 3+) is about _values_.  You can't meaningfully ask `if "100" < 90: ...` for example, and it doesn't matter what variable name or function call was evaluated to get that string and that integer.

Comment: @SteveBroberg:  As a resource for a C* programmer, I highly recommend the 3-hour tutorial by Stuart Williams: "Python Epiphanies" (2013: [video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=9mgg45Wr8jY), [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/tutorial-python-epiphanies-by-stuart-williams)).  He starts with assignment statements (including `class`, `def`, `import`... you know, just like in C++), and works his way deep into the _really_ surprising stuff.  He has a slightly longer [2014 version](https://youtube.com/watch?v=Uyj2UFTL_vg), but I couldn't find the slides for it.